# Magento 1.9 - Promotions Conditions and Actions not showing

Tags: magento-1.9, promotions

I have a problem creating the promotion rules for magento, the Add button Conditions and Action does not work.. I click on it but nothing happens.. Has anyone ever gone through this?

Conditions:
[image]

Actions:
[image]

I tried to follow this step:

> Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes > SKU Change "Use for Promo
>   Rule Conditions" to "Yes"

But it did not work.. 
It's as if the click of the + button was not called, it does not open anything..

Any idea?

Comment: have you try a reindex?

Comment: Yes, but no work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

> System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> JavaScript
>   Settings -> Merge Javascript Files = No